# Have another question about straight lines

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I made a question about this topic some hours ago and i found another problem that i can't solve. I hope this is not against the rules of "homework".

So i have the following lines:
$$L1: P1(1, 1, 2) + n1(1, 2, 0)$$
$$L2: P2(2, 2, 0) + n2(1, -1, 1)$$
$$L3: P3(0, 3, -2) + n3(5, 0, 2) $$

Get the equation of the straight line that cuts these lines L1, L2, L3 in M, N and Q respectively so MN = NQ.

What i have done was:

get the parametric equations
L1: $$x = 1 + n1$$
    $$y = 1 + 2 * n1$$
    $$z = 2$$

L2: $$x = 2 + n2$$
    $$y = 2 - n2$$
    $$z = n2$$

L3: $$x = 5 * n3$$
    $$y = 3$$
    $$z = -2 + 2 * n3$$

Now i have 2 segments that are equal but i don't know what are the points of those segments. How should i follow? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: no. it looks like you have tried to solve it yourself, so it is not against any rules. I'll even upvote your question. :)

Comment: Do you know the section formula(I don't know what it is called in other countries)? $\frac{mx_1+nx_2}{m+n}$

Comment: Try to use this in the following way. $2x_{l2}=x_{l1}+x_{l3}$ same thing for $y$ and $z$

Comment: Sorry, i had to go to sleep. And no, i don't know this formula but if I'm understanding it correctly, you are just working with each vector separately. What i don't get yet is how do you go from the first formula to what you have second?

Comment: if I just substitute $m=n=1$, because the point $N$ divides $MQ$ in ratio $1:1$

Comment: oh lol, you are right, thanks, i'm going to work from there.